# Mass tag fixing (large ogg audio collection)

Tags: sound, music, ogg-vorbis, mp3-tag

I have a lot of ogg files of pop music.

Unfortunately the tags are not normalized.

Example: One album has "Tina Turner" as interpreter and the next album has "Turner Tina".

It would be nice to normalize the tags.

I looked ad Picard, but the [quick start guide](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/quick-start/) tells me:

> You should note - Picard is not built to be a mass single-track tag fixer.

How to mass tag fix on Ubuntu?

I don't want a GUI. I am hoping that this process is automated. There are just too many files. I can't fix tags by hand and per single file.

This should be automated:

1. tool looks at the current tags of one audio file.
2. tool tries to guess the album and title with the help of some internet database
3. tool should normalize the tags if a valid album+title was found in the DB
4. the tool should skip the file if no valid album+title was found and print a warning.

With other words: I don't want to set "Tina Tuner" by script or GUI myself.

I have Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

Check `lltag`

From the man page: 
`lltag` is a command-line tool to automatically set tags of MP3, OGG or FLAC files.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/lltag.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Check `exiftool` from the package

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

A command line tool to set and read meta information in multimedia files.  There's an extensive man page with nice examples of how to make it run well.

Comment: I updated the question. See "This should be automated:" I guess exiftool can't to this. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @guettli It would not be automated, but I'm unsure wherea program would obtain the data that you want to use for tags.  Can you elaborate on that in your question?  For example, most cameras will tag with date, some with location.  Music vendors frequently tag with information about the music, such as artist...

Comment: there are already tags which where created by SoundJuicer or the command line tool abcde. This question is about fixing/normalizing the tags.

Comment: @guettli Exif tools would be able to read the data currently there, and write new data into place.  But....  The in between bit (changing turner, tina to tina turner) would require a bit of scripting.

Comment: the in between bit would require ... I would be able to do this. But I have other things which I prefer (family, sport, ....) I guess someone, somewhere has solved the in between bit already.

Comment: You and I both!  Although I have personally committed to finally learning AWK, and the PERL

Comment: One last comment (before this thing makes us use chat)  Picard supports full albums now, and kid3 might be good for you.  [https://picard.musicbrainz.org/](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) and [https://kid3.sourceforge.io/](https://kid3.sourceforge.io/)